# Static initialization of a struct with class members

Tags: c++, constructor, struct, static-initializer

I have a struct that's defined with a large number of vanilla `char*` pointers, but also an object member. When I try to statically initialize such a struct, I get a compiler error.

```
typedef struct 
{
    const char* pszA;
    // ... snip ...
    const char* pszZ;

    SomeObject obj;
} example_struct;

// I only want to assign the first few members, the rest should be default
example_struct ex = { "a", "b" };
```

`SomeObject` has a public default constructor with no arguments, so I didn't think this would be a problem. But when I try to compile this (using VS), I get the following error:

```
error C2248: 'SomeObject::SomeObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'SomeObject'
```

Any idea why?

**Update:** Here's the definition of SomeObject

```
class SomeObject
{
    void operator=(const SomeObject&);
    SomeObject(const SomeObject&);
public:
    SomeObject()
        {
            // etc
        }

    // members snipped
}
```

Comment: As an aside, the normal way to declare a struct in C++ would be to just do `struct example_struct` like you would with a class (except for using `struct` instead of `class`) and skip the whole typedef thing. You're stuck doing that in C, but there's no need for it in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initialization of `ex` performs *copy-initialization*. It takes the value on the right and uses it to initialize the variable on the left. For class-type members, the appropriate constructor is used. In your case, that means invoking the copy constructor for `SomeObject`, but you've made that constructor private, so the compiler is correct in telling you that `SomeObject::SomeObject` is a private member that can't be accessed.

Although the compiler is allowed to elide the *call* to the copy constructor and initialize `ex.obj` directly with the default constructor, that is an optional optimization; it still needs to be *allowed* to call the copy constructor.

You can either give `example_struct` a constructor of your own and use that in place of brace initialization, or you can publicize `SomeObject`'s copy constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The rest of the members will be initialized to '0', not "default", right?   So it's probably trying to call `SomeObject(0)`, which I'd guess is resolving to a private copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the constructor for SomeObject is private.

Comment: "SomeObject has a public default constructor with no arguments"